# Puma .state file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, puma

I'm attempting to deploy my rails application w/ puma using Capistrano. Towards the end ofthe deployment it attempts to run

`bundle exec pumactl -S /home/deployer/production/shared/sockets/puma.state restart`

which fails w/

```
undefined method `has_key?' for false:FalseClass.
```

I have simply created a empty file for `puma.state`. My question is what exactly is this file and what is supposed to be in it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puma has a state file that records the PID of the process. If you are deploying for the first time, you should delete the .state file, and do a

`cap deploy:cold`

or, you can start puma manually using something like

`cap puma:start`

This will start the process and create a valid state file. Here is my puma start command in capistrano:

```
namespace :puma do

  desc "Start the application"
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec puma -t 8:32 -b 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/puma.sock' -S #{shared_path}/sockets/puma.state --control 'unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/pumactl.sock' >> #{shared_path}/log/puma-#{rails_env}.log 2>&1 &", :pty => false
  end
  after "deploy:start", "puma:start"
end
```